# How do i update the title option in an angular-nv3d piechart

Tags: angularjs, scope, nvd3.js

I am using nvd3 piechart to show the size of the overall files in a folder.
my question is how to update the title of the chart after each data update is happening (for example to show the overall size in the title.
i tried using an object in the scope which does update with the currect size, but it does not update in the title option in the chart)

here is my code:

```
app.controller("chartCtrl", function($scope, foldersSrvc){

$scope.options = {
    chart: {
        type: "pieChart",
        height: 400,
        showLabels: true,
    labelType: "value",
    title: "Content(" + $scope.filesSize + ")",
        labelSunbeamLayout: true,
        x: function(d){return d.type;},
    y: function(d){return d.size;},
        donut: true
    }
};

foldersSrvc.getFiles("server").then(function(data){
$scope.data = data;
$scope.filesSize = foldersSrvc.getFilesSize(data);
});

$scope.$on('folderClicked', function(event, args){
foldersSrvc.getFiles(args.id).then(function(data){
  $scope.data = data;
  $scope.filesSize = foldersSrvc.getFilesSize(data);
});
})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend the angular wrapper for nvd3, [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/) to support data binding.

```
angular.module('myApp', ['nvd3'])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    /* Chart options */
    $scope.options = { /* JSON data */ };

    /* Chart data */
    $scope.data = { /* JSON data */ }

})
```

html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, that's actually what i used, but after you wrote it down as its just a JSON object i just updated it in the functions, and it works fine (i just didn't notice it before), thank you!